# Echo JSON PHP array WIKI API

Tags: php, json

I don't know who to export API

So the URL is:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=pageimages&format=json&pithumbsize=200&titles=Jean-Claude%20Van%20Damme

And I get

```
 {"batchcomplete":"","query":{"pages":{"89265":  {"pageid":89265,"ns":0,"title":"Jean-Claude Van Damme","thumbnail":{"source":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/27/Jean-Claude_Van_Damme_2012.jpg/141px-Jean-Claude_Van_Damme_2012.jpg","width":141,"height":200},"pageimage":"Jean-Claude_Van_Damme_2012.jpg"}}}}
```

Who can I only export the source?

Now I have this code:

```
$json=file_get_contents("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=pageimages&format=json&pithumbsize=200&titles=$title");

$details=json_decode($json);

echo $details['thumbnail']['source'];
```

So who I do?

Comment: `var_dump($details);` it is object, not array.

Comment: Ok thank you, but you dont say who i resolve it :)

Comment: tell json_decode to return an array by adding `true` as 2nd parameter `$details=json_decode($json,true);`

Comment: Not relevant to your question, but see my edit - the word you wanted was "how" not "who".

Answer (score 0):

You could use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) and pass `true` as the second parameter.

From the documentation:

> When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.

Then I think what you are looking for is this:

```
$json=file_get_contents("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=pageimages&format=json&pithumbsize=200&titles=Jean-Claude%20Van%20Damme");
$details=json_decode($json, true);
$source = $details['query']['pages']['89265']['thumbnail']['source'];

echo $source;
```

Will result in:

> https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/27/Jean-Claude_Van_Damme_2012.jpg/141px-Jean-Claude_Van_Damme_2012.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$json = file_get_contents("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=pageimages&format=json&pithumbsize=200&titles=Jean-Claude%20Van%20Damme");

$details = json_decode($json);

$pages = $details->query->pages;    

$output = '';
foreach ($pages as $pageid => $content){ 
    $image_url = $content->thumbnail->source;
    $title = $content->title;
    $output .= '<img src="'.$image_url.'"/>'.$title;
}

echo $output;
```